# Airflow not backfilling the missing dates

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

I know there are already a couple of questions open on this topic but I can't find a satisfying answer to my situation.

Why is Airflow not correctly backfilling for all the dates:

[image]

I think that I've correctly set the default argument:

```
default_args = {
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1),
    'catchup':True,
    schedule_interval= "0 0 * * *",
    'retries': 0
}
```

I've run some manual dag triggers and some part have been backfilled but not others I don't understand why...

My understand is that since I've set `catchup` to `True` and that I've defined a `start_date` the dag should be executed on all the 'missing' date between the start date and the current date...

#edit1

in addition I can see that when I'm clearing a tag previously executed the backfilling is working. Why is the backfilling not working for a date when a dag as not been executed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `catchup` to `True`, Airflow scheduler checks after each run if the next run is missing, and it creates it, but it doesn't check the previous runs and the history because this affects the performance when you have a lot of runs in the Metastore.

If you want to backfill the previous runs you have two solutions:

- clear a previous run (the last task of the run) of a missing period
- use the CLI and execute the backfill command which check if there is missing runs between two dates and it runs them (the terminal session should stay alive until the end of the backfill, so try to use [screen](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/))

Comment: It's obvious to me now that you've explained it like this but I guess I needed this clarification. thanks!